# Translate UI Bootstrap tooltip from ng-repeat value

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-translate

I cannot get the tooltip display translated value (using angular translate) from an object in `ng-repeat` loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
            <div>
                <span ng-bind-html="type.icon"></span>&nbsp;
                <label style="font-size: 20px;">{{type.nameNormal | translate}}</label>
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"
                   tooltip-class="custom-tooltip"
                   uib-tooltip="{{'type.descriptionNormal' | translate}}"
                   tooltip-placement="bottom"></i>
                <hr class="hr-no-background">
            </div>
        </div>
```

P.S. UI Bootstrap version: 0.13.4
     Angular: 1.4.4

Comment: Why are you using `'type.descriptionNormal'` as it is a key for some value, use `type.descriptionNormal` ---------- without single quotes

Comment: That doesn't work also, the tooltip is just not displayed

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 0.13.4 of ui bootstrap the directives are not prefixed with the 'uib' prefix yet

see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/tooltip for details

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those, who will face equal problem in the future: I just didn't put any value into my translation file for the `descriptionNormal`.

Example:

```
type.descriptionNormal = "DESCRIPTION"
```

Translation file:
`"DESCRIPTION": ""`

This was the case. Now everything work fine.

So it seams the tooltip doesn't get displayed if the value is empty.